# wowza rtmp input and rtmps output

Tags: wowza, rtmps

I have a wowza server receiving RMTP video and sending RTMP video, this works flawless.

Now I need to add ssl suport, so I configured the streamlock and is working well receiving RTMPS from ffmpeg as encoder and sending RTMPS to users with flowplayer.

But I need to make it works with VidiU Encoder, and this device do not support RTMPS protocol, it only works sending video using RTMP.

Then I tried to send RTMP video (using VidiU) to the sever (with streamlock enabled) to send RTMPS video to users, but it don't work for me, I don't know which configuration is needed in wowza to do this. any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

On the menu: **Wowza> Server >Virtual Host Setup** for Streamlock configuration I have 2 host ports:

[image]

I added a third Host Port with the following configuration:

- Type: streaming
- IP: *
- Port: **1934**
- SSL/StreamLock Enabled: **false**

Yes I used port 1934 instead of 1935 because this is used for the RTMPS protocol.

This way on the encoder side, the RTMP address must go to the 1934 port (rtmp://[server_ip]:1934/streamapp/ ).

With this configuration, the incoming stream is an RTMP stream to the port 1934 and the outcoming stream will be an RTMPS stream.

Now my configuration looks like this:

[image]